# Plot Continuous Line With 2 Points

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any way to plot a continuous line with pgfplot/tikz using only 2 points (i.e. it will extend past those points on its own) within the domain I specify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `shorten` with a negative length to extend the edge.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {A};
\node [right of=a,node distance=3em] (b) {B};
\draw [shorten >=-3em,shorten <=-3em] (a) edge (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-90](2,2){A}(4,2){B}
    \pstLineAB[nodesep=-1]{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Miscellaneous

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\multido{\r=.0+-0.2}{11}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-90](2,2){A}(4,2){B}
    \pstLineAB[nodesep=\r]{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use linear regression to compute the line for you, and draw it for the ddesire domain.
The code below provides specifies the points `(1,1)` and `(3,5)` and plots the line between them for the  `domain=-5:5`:

[image]

### Notes:

- This may be overkill depending on your application, but this solution provides an actual "graph" of the line between the two points (which may or may not be desirable).
- Note that this does not seem to work for vertical lines, so that will require special handling.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
     axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
     xlabel=$x$,
     ylabel=$y$,
     grid,
     ]
  \addplot table [y={create col/linear regression={}}]
  {
    X    Y
    1    1
    3    5
  };
    \xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona}   
    \xdef\yintercept{\pgfplotstableregressionb}
  \addplot [draw= red, ultra thick, domain=-5:5] (x,\slope*x+\yintercept);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another way with tikzlibraly `calc` to extend the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {A};
\node [right of=a,node distance=3em] (b) {B};
\draw ($(a)!-1.5em!(b)$) -- ($(a)!4.5em!(b)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```